Why joined report doesn't work with polymorphic relationship field?
Why joined report doesn't work with polymorphic relationship field?
RecordId or EntityId field is a standard polymorphic relationship field which has relationship to many objects including Knowledge__kav.
However, we can't create a Joined Report using Knowledge Article Versions report with a Topic Assignment report.
Is this a bug or a design flaw?


Design flaw. Join(ing/ed) reports is a very, very limited feature.

Salesforce standard report functionality is quite limited especially when we are talking about joined reports.
For such case we use Tableau reports. It is important to note that this is additionally paid service.
